# MySQL: How to constraint couple of values with set of couples of values via JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

### Question

With MySQL and **using a JDBC template**, is there a way to build parameters from Java Lists so that the **SQL request matches a couple of values with couples of values in a given set**?

---

### Details

The values should match only if the couple of values is present in the list.

It should **not** match if one is present in a couple of values and the other in another couple further into the list of couples.

That is to say, given that JDBC parametrized query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE (COL_1, COL_2) IN (:valuesSet)
```

**Caution**: valuesSet is a set of **couples**

And that Java code:

```java
public void daoMethod(List<MyObject> values1, List<MyObject> values2) {
    String query = "";
    query = "SELECT *\n" +
            "FROM TABLE_1\n" +
            "WHERE (COL_1, COL_2) IN (:valuesSet)";

    MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();

    // Build valuesSet here

    parameters.addValue("valuesSet", valuesSet);
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(query, parameters);
}
```

Is there an elegant way to build a JDBC template without having to "manually" create the string?

The inserted `:valuesSet` should be something like:

```java
"(values1.get(0), values2.get(0)), (values1.get(1), values2.get(1)), ..."
```

But how should I build that string?

---

### Current Track

Currently, my first draft solution is to build the string by Java code like this:

```java
List<String> valuesSet = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < values1.size(); i++) {
    String value1 = StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql(values1.get(i).toString());
    String value2 = StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql(values2.get(i).toString());

    valuesSet.add("('" + value1 + "','" + value2 + "')");
}
```

But it keeps escaping the result list to make it a String and adds `'` around it. Therefore, it's not working.

---

### TL;DR

Input:

```
List<Object> objects
```

Output:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE (COL_1, COL_2) IN (
    ('object_1_val1', 'object_1_val2'),
    ('object_2_val1', 'object_2_val2'),
    ('object_3_val1', 'object_3_val2'),
    ('object_4_val1', 'object_4_val2'),
    ...
)
```

Mean:

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate
```

Comment: So the SQL basically works? `(1, 2) IN ((3, 4), (1, 2), (5, 2))` -> 1 result? I would have made a temporary table with those values, and do a join. Which does not help parametrising.

Comment: @JoopEggen yes, `IN` can work that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a workaround using **CONCAT()**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE CONCAT(COL_1, ',', COL_2) IN (:valuesSet);
```

That way, valuesSet can be a simple list of strings and is passed as the following:

```java
List<String> valuesSet = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < values1.size(); i++) {
    String value1 = StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql(values1.get(i).toString());
    String value2 = StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql(values2.get(i).toString());

    valuesSet.add(value1 + "," + value2;
}
```

parameters.addValue("valuesSet", valuesSet);

Then, the executed query is something like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE CONCAT(COL_1, ',', COL_2) IN (
    'object_1_val1,object_2_val1',
    'object_1_val2,object_2_val2',
    'object_1_val3,object_2_val3',
    'object_1_val4,object_2_val4',
    ...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use every value separately.

```
List<String> valuesSet = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder sqlIn = new SqlBuilder();    
for (int i = 0; i < values1.size(); i++) {
    sqlIn.append("(?, ?),");
    valuesSet.add(values1.get(i).toString());
    valuesSet.add(values2.get(i).toString());
}
```

Comment: Would that mean I raised an example where `jdbcTemplate` is more suited than `namedParameterJdbcTemplate`?

Comment: Named would be nicer, but how? - I am doing O/R for a while now. A case of "RTFM"

Comment: Well I found a dirty workaround with `WHERE CONCAT(COL_1, COL_2) IN (:values)` which reduces the problem to a simple list but is everything but elegant imo.

Comment: Write it as an answer so others might find a solution.